# I18n pluralize children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

So I've seen you can pluralize something easily.

```
parent:
    child:
        one: there were one!
        many: there were many!

I18n.t('parent.child', count: 1)
```

But what if you wanted to pluralize something with children that had pluralizations?

```
parent:
    child:
        foo:
            one: there was a foo!
            many: there were many foos!
        bar: a cool bar
        ...
```

I've got an ugly method that looks like

```
I18n.t('parent.child').merge( foo: I18n.t( 'parent.child.foo', count: 1 ) )
```

Is there some better way?